# Blank page on Magento 2.0 install on LEMP

Tags: magento2, installation

Server LEMP (based on Ubuntu 15.04)

I downloaded and extracted Magento 2.0.1 in `/var/www/magento2`
my `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/magento2` is

```
# special mapping to redirect my different websites
map $HTTP_HOST $mage_run_code {
   www.mage.dev default;
   eu.mage.dev eu;
}
upstream fastcgi_backend {
   server   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    server_name www.mage.dev eu.mage.dev;



    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento2;
    set $MAGE_MODE developer;
    set $mage_run_type website;

    root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

    index index.php;
    autoindex off;
    charset off;

    add_header 'X-Content-Type-Options' 'nosniff';
    add_header 'X-XSS-Protection' '1; mode=block';

    location /setup {
        root $MAGE_ROOT;
        location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
            fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        }
    }

    location /update {
        root $MAGE_ROOT;

        location ~ ^/update/index.php {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny everything but index.php
        location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        }
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location /pub {
        location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
            deny all;
        }
        alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }

    location /static/ {
        if ($MAGE_MODE = "production") {
            expires max;
        }
        location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            expires +1y;

            if (!-f $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
            }
        }
        location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            expires    off;

            if (!-f $request_filename) {
               rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
            }
        }
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }

    location /media/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;

        location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            expires +1y;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
        }
        location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            expires    off;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
        }
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }

    location /media/customer/ {
        deny all;
    }

    location /media/downloadable/ {
        deny all;
    }

    location /media/import/ {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ cron\.php {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;

        fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
        fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=256M \n max_execution_time=600";
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_MODE $MAGE_MODE;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE $mage_run_type;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE $mage_run_code;    
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Now I query `http://www.mage.dev/setup/` and I get an almost blank page, just grey area at the top. With Chrome handy F12 developer tools, I get :

```
GET http://www.mage.dev/setup/index.php/navigation/header-bar 403 (Forbidden)   angular.js:7715
GET http://www.mage.dev/setup/index.php/navigation 403 (Forbidden)   angular.js:7715
GET http://www.mage.dev/setup/index.php/navigation/header-bar 403 (Forbidden)   angular.js:7715
```

Also, to be sure with the permission, I ran `sudo chmod -R 0777 /var/www/magento2` (I know the security risks, but here, I am trying to debug)

I have been looking around like crazy and can not find any solution, how to solve?

Comment: is your problem fixed?

Comment: @AniruddhaADeshpande Did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

From your root magento install dir try some commands

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 0750 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 0640 {} \; 
find var pub/media pub/static -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;  //Setting group write and sgid bit permissions for writable directories
find var pub/media pub/static -type f -not -name .htaccess -exec chmod g+w {} \;
chmod g+w app/etc
find -L vendor/bin -type f -exec chmod u+x {} \;
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Hope this will helps you

Comment: unsuccessful  ! :(

Comment: See `/var/log/nginx/error.log` to debug this. You should check rule config of nginx

Comment: it all start with a  `2016/02/02 18:19:38 [error] 11445#0: *8 open() "/var/www/magento_2.0.1/setup/pub/angular-clickout/angular-clickout.min.js.map" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.0.3, server: test.example.com, request: "GET /setup/pub/angular-clickout/angular-clickout.min.js.map HTTP/1.1", host: "test.example.com"`

Comment: I have been going through the config again and again....

Answer (score 1):

:

```
$ sudo  mv /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-available/default_org
$ sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

Paste the below lines in default file.

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento2;
        set $MAGE_MODE developer;


    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;
root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

index index.php;
autoindex off;
charset off;

location /setup {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;
    location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

location /update {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;

    location ~ ^/update/index.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny everything but index.php
    location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location /pub {
    location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
        deny all;
    }
    alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /static/ {
    if ($MAGE_MODE = "production") {
        expires max;
    }

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    location ~ ^/static/version {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
           rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;

    location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/customer/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/downloadable/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/import/ {
    deny all;
}

location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;

    fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=768M \n max_execution_time=600";
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_param  MAGE_MODE $MAGE_MODE;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types
    text/plain
    text/css
    text/js
    text/xml
    text/javascript
    application/javascript
    application/x-javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/xml+rss;

location ~ \.php$ {
    deny all;
}
    }
```

I am adding a link. where i have mentioned all the steps in brief to make it easy installation of magento2 on Lemp.