# Magento2 - Nginx : Not able to install getting 404 error

Tags: magento2, installation, nginx, php-7

I'm running Apache and Nginx on Ubuntu 14.04 machine.
Nginx + PHP7.0-FPM configured on 8080 port and apache is on 80 ( default port ).

Stack :

- PHP Version : 7.0.14-1
- Nginx : nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
- Magento version : 2.1.2
- Installation method : Magento Composer

Configuration file created here `/etc/nginx/sites-available/magento2.`

Below code used in file.

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
           server 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    server {

            listen 8080;
            server_name 127.0.0.1:8080;
            set $MAGE_ROOT /usr/share/nginx/html/magento2/project-community-edition/;
            set $MAGE_MODE developer;
            include /usr/share/nginx/html/magento2/project-community-edition/nginx.conf.sample;
    }
```

**404 Error while loading angular.js resource**
[image: 404 Error while loading angular.js resource]

Similar to this problem :

1. [Blank page on Magento 2.0 install on LEMP](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99143/blank-page-on-magento-2-0-install-on-lemp)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35445606/1942109

Comment: why you cal 127.0.0.1:8080? if your main port is apache 80?

Comment: was this ever resolved? :)